# Execute several functions using pipeline

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and in order to process it and create a new dataframe with the rows of interest I execute the next code, which works fine:

```
arrivals <- arrivals[, c(2, 40:64)]
arrivals <- arrivals[complete.cases(arrivals), ]
medias <- rowMeans(arrivals[3:26])

# We select rows that we are interested in
map <- arrivals[c(44,165,40,84,111,158,26), ]
```

I would like a way of doing this using pipelines.

Something like:

```
map <- arrivals[, c(2, 40:64)] %>%
       arrivals[complete.cases(arrivals), ] %>%
       arrivals[c(44,165,40,84,111,158,26), ]
```

However this doesn´t work.

Comment: I suggest you read some more from `magrittr`'s documentation (e.g., https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/). One should never have to refer to the original frame name again in the pipeline (unless the intent truly is to reflect on original data despite what the pipeline has changed/filtered/added since the start of the pipe). The different stages of a pipeline are typically littered with *verb*-like functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is the same as of akrun. Here we use `na.omit` thus I think we don't need `na.rm = TRUE` to calculate the row means:

```
library(dplyr)
map <- arrivals %>% 
    select(2, 40:64) %>% 
    na.omit() %>% 
    mutate(medias = rowMeans(select(., 3:26))) %>% 
    slice(26, 40, 44, 84, 111, 158, 165)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `select/slice` to subset the columns/rows respectively and `filter` out the `NA` elements in 'arrivals' with `complete.cases`

```
library(dplyr)
arrivals %>%
   select(2, 40:64) %>%
   filter(complete.cases(arrivals)) %>%
   mutate(medias = rowMeans(select(., 3:26), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   slice(44, 165, 40, 84, 111, 158, 26)
```